# emulator not showing in adb devices

Tags: android, android-emulator

if i start an emulator using the android SDK r12 it does not show up in the adb devices list

win7 64 // android 2.2 (not an actual hardware device - just the emulator)

what could be the problem?

Comment: May be changing the emulator booting mode can help.By default emulator runs on snapshot boot mode, changed it to cold boot mode.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can also try to :

```
 adb kill-server
 adb start-server
```

to restart the `adb server`. Maybe something went wrong with the `adb-server`. This happens a lot, and many such issues can be solved by restarting the server.

Comment: I am trying to automate unit testing on our home grown CI system. Even though I restart adb it looks like it still cannot work with emulator instance though it gets to see the device. It times out with an error message. Any ideas to work around this issue.

Comment: How can I attach Andriod Emulator created by Andriod Sutdio to the list ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are at the path and give command.

```
android-sdk_r12-windows\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>adb devices
```

I am also using win7 64 It is working for me. If you are getting any error. Mention it.

Also make sure that USB debugging is enabled in your device.

> ```
> Settings>Applications>Development>USB debugging
> ```

Can you able to  see device in eclipse?
If not then close your emulator and open it again.

Comment: My question: How do you enable USB debugging in device if the screen is completely destroyed? I'm trying to back-door in for some things mainly my Google Authenticator numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes even adb itself bugs, for me always works good old pkill:

```
pkill -9 adb
```