# Error on ionic emulate android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am just starting my adventure with mobile app development (and with ionic). I try to emulate a sample ionic project which I created with ionic start blank. 
Running

```
ionic emulate android
```

returns the following error:

```
Running command: /home/ja/Projects/test/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/ja/Projects/test
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: /home/ja/Projects/test/platforms/android/cordova/run --emulator
ANDROID_HOME=/home/ja/android-sdk-linux/
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65
WARNING : no emulator specified, defaulting to MyAndroid-5.1.1
Waiting for emulator...
emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check
Booting up emulator (this may take a while)....................................................


/home/ja/Projects/test/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126 
    throw e;
          ^
Error executing "adb -s emulator-5554 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim": error: device 'emulator-5554' not found
Error: /home/ja/Projects/test/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 1
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

Could you please help?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

My .bashrc contains the following:

```
export ANDROID_SDK=/home/ja/android-sdk-linux/
export ANDROID_NDK=/home/ja/android-sdk-linux/
export ANDROID_HOME="$ANDROID_SDK"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools"
export ANDROID_TOOLS="$ANDROID_HOME/tools"

export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_SDK:$ANDROID_NDK:$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS:$ANDROID_TOOLS

export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true
```

Comment: May be your ANDROID_HOME variable might be incorrectly setup.you need to include the Android SDK's tools and platform-tools in your PATH environment variable

Comment: i guess I have them all in my path (.bashrc added to the description of my question)

Comment: Just remove your android platform and add again

Comment: did you try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576704/phonegap-cordova-android-development

Comment: I included the part related to android to the description of my question.

Comment: lets chat here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95769/ionic-installation-problem

Comment: I removed the whole stuff (andorid sdk, cordova, ionic) and reinstalled. The problme remians...

Comment: did you build this using phone(ionic run android)?

Comment: No, i build using: ionic build android

Comment: Just test this app by phone(using ionic run android command)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the 'emulator-5554' device can't be found.

Try to reset the adb server.

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

There are some issues which can be solved by this one.
**Source:** [Stack Overflow answer on a related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7502359/3423342)

Comment: thanks mhx, I have tried that, but still the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

According to your logs:

```
Error executing "adb -s emulator-5554 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim": error: device 'emulator-5554' not found
```

It means you haven't created emulator. It might happen you have created then try to create one more emulator and then try emulate command.

Comment: I have removed the existing avds and created the new one. Still no success.